# where is the definition of _cudnn_convolution_full_forward in pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

as the title mentioned, I want to find the definition of _cudnn_convolution_full_forward, but I search through all the project
in pytorch and failed. And I cannot find and doc about this function.

any one can help me?

Comment: it would be tough but I wonder why do you need it?

Comment: I want to know the return value of this function and its semantics, but I cannot find any doc about this unpublic api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the cudnn convolution functions are defined here:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/1848cad10802db9fa0aa066d9de195958120d863/aten/src/ATen/native/cudnn/Conv.cpp

This function doesn't exist anymore in the latest versions of pytorch. The closest thing that there is there is `cudnn_convolution_forward`. In version 0.1.12, the function is in the same file: 
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/v0.1.12/torch/csrc/cudnn/Conv.cpp

I would recommend against using using an unpublic api (one starting with `_`) and use a public method instead, but you probably already know that.

In otherwords you should be using

```
torch.backends.cudnn.enabled = True
```

and then `conv2d` or `conv3d` depending on your use.

Comment: I cannot find the same unpublic api in the the link you provided,

Comment: I cannot find the same unpublic name in the link you provided, does it mean that the name of these unpublic name has changed by the developers of pytorch.




for example:
_cudnn_convolution_backward_data（0.1.12） => _cudnn_convolution_backward_input

_cudnn_convolution_backward_filer（0.1.12） => _cudnn_convolution_backward_weight





I am using the 0.1.12 pytorch, maybe pytorch's version you provided is higher than 0.1.12?

Comment: Yes, exactly, here is version 0.1.12 where your function is defined: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/v0.1.12/torch/csrc/cudnn/Conv.cpp